# Pruebas unitarias C#

Tags: c#, pruebas-unitarias

Tengo que realizar una serie de pruebas unitarias, y recién estoy empezando y no tengo muy claro como hacerlas.

Tengo una interfaz `IPersona` con algunos metodos, y el que estoy probando es ese:

```
string nombreCompleto();
```

Y la clase `Persona` esta así:

```
    private string nombre;
    private string apellido;
    private int edad;
    private int kmRecorridos;
    private bool vivo;
    private Persona pareja;

    public Persona()
    {
        this.nombre = "";
        this.apellido = "";
        this.edad = 0;
        this.kmRecorridos = 0;
        this.pareja = null;
        nacer();
    }

    public Persona(string n, string a, int e)
    {
        this.nombre = n;
        this.apellido = a;
        this.edad = e;
        this.pareja = null;
        this.kmRecorridos = 0;
        nacer();
    }

    public string nombreCompleto()
    {
        return "Nombre Completo: " + this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }
```

Estoy realizando la prueba de la siguiente manera, pero he probado algunas cosas y no se como hacerla exitosa:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mockPersona = new Mock<IPersona>();

        mockPersona.Setup(x => x.nombreCompleto()).Returns("Nombre completo " + "" + " " + "");

        IPersona persona = (IPersona) new Persona();           

        Assert.AreEqual(persona.nombreCompleto(), ((IPersona) mockPersona.Object).nombreCompleto());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya esta solucionado. Tenia un pequeño error en el `.Setup()` el cual la cadena que le estaba pasando no estaba bien escrita.

Por otro lado, he realizado el test de otra forma:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestNombreCompleto()
    {
        var mockPersona = new Mock<IPersona>();

        mockPersona.Setup(x => x.nombreCompleto()).Returns("Nombre Completo: " + "Juan" + " " + "Perez");

        Persona p = new Persona();
        p.setNombre("Juan");
        p.setApellido("Perez");
        IPersona persona = (IPersona) p ;           

        Assert.AreEqual(persona.nombreCompleto(), ((IPersona) mockPersona.Object).nombreCompleto());
    }
```

Y así ha funcionado. Espero que sirva de ayuda a futuros problemas.